# Indentation error in developer console

Tags: developer-console

```
  System.debug('allowwwwwwww'+strName);
            List<work> a = new List<work> {};
                set<String> process = new set<String>{};

                    Integer Cnt = 0;
            Integer marks;
```

When I indent the above lines using developer console logs "edit->indentation"its not getting indented.Can someone identify the cause?

Comment: Is the above code part of some class?

Comment: Select entire code then try to indent

Comment: Yes..I tried that too.. problem is other lines of the code are getting indented except these line

Comment: Use Eclipse IDE to do that. Developer Console is pain sometimes!

Comment: Yea.That's a better way but I am confused about why only that particular line of the code is not getting indented in developer console..

Comment: It's because {}; parts. I noticed that too. It's weird but Dev Console indents code after {}; parts.

Comment: Oh.is it  possible to rectify that error?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have typos in your code. Those braces should  be parens. `List<work> a = new List<work> {};` should be written as `List<work> a = new List<work>();` Once you do that, your problem should disappear. Apex is a strongly typed language and the Dev Console is picking up the error while Eclipse might not because it isn't native to just Apex.

Comment: Do you have a commented out line or comment block above that section?